# vfprintf_unlocked() equivalent?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, centos7, glibc

I noticed that IBM z/OS 2.3.0 [offers vfprintf_unlocked()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/vfprtf.htm).

Tho, I can't find an equivalent in glibc (2.17 on CentOS 7).  Is that function IBM specific?  Or is it available in some headers?  If not, any function similar to `vfprintf_unlocked()` that is lighter (e.g. no thread safe) and can take `printf`'s format string to write to file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `__fsetlocking (`*`stream`*`, FSETLOCKING_BYCALLER)` to advise glibc that the locking will performed externally.  In this case, calling regular functions like `vfprintf` on *`stream`* will perform no locking.  See the [stdio_ext(3) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio_ext.3.html) for additional information.

It is also possible to call the [`flockfile` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html), which is also part of POSIX.  In the glibc implementation, no atomic operation is performed on subsequent stream function calls such as `vfprintf`, which also avoids the locking overhead.

Both operations are sticky and persist across calls to the `_unlocked` functions, until their effects is reverted by another call to `__fsetlocking` or to `funlockfile`.

In both cases, the net result will be that there is virtually no performance difference between the existing `_unlocked` functions and the regular ones, except where the `_unlocked` variant is implemented as an inline function or macro (as in `putc_unlocked`).

Comment: Thanks!  Just one more related question -- given that `__fsetlocking (stream, FSETLOCKING_BYCALLER)` advises (the verb sounds like there is no guarantee?) glibc that the locking will be performed externally, does it mean that `fwrite()` and `fwrite_unlocked()` with the same file stream have no difference in terms of performance (i.e. both use no lock)?  Similarly, `fflush()` and `fflush_unlocked()` have no difference?  Just don't want to make sure those functions with `_unlocked()` suffix won't reset the internal "no lock flag".  Thanks!

Comment: The flag/lock is sticky, so you can call `_unlocked` functions, but you do not have to.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find an equivalent in glibc (2.17 on CentOS 7).

There isn't one. To see which functions are available, do this:

```
nm -D /path/to/libc.so.6 | grep '_unlocked$'
```

In general, the `vfprintf` is so "heavy", the overhead of locking and unlocking the stream will not be enough to matter, unless you do something extremely suboptimal, such as printing a single character at a time.